# $LK-\Phi$ proof of $\exists y Pby$

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I am having difficulty with the concept of $LK-\Phi$ proofs, here is a question I have been working on:

> Let $\Phi = \{Pafa\}$, where $P$ is a binary predicate symbol and $f$ is a unary function symbol. Give an $LK-\Phi$ proof of $\exists y Pby$. You do not need to show exchanges and weakenings.

My intution for these questions is very little unless it is blatantly obvious over what to do, but I do know that in the system $LK$ we have a $LK-\Phi$ proof if we have $A\to A$ or $\to A$ where $A\in\Phi$. So in this situation I think I set this up as the following:

$$\to \exists y Pby$$and then I would have a sequent above it where I would apply the $\exists R$ rule, which would create the sequent above as: $$\to Pba$$ but from here I am not sure at all what to do whether I need to rely on some sort of trick or anything? Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated, this is for an exam I am studying.

Comment: May you clarify the definition of LK-$\Phi$ proof ? Can you point at a textbook ? Are you allowed to use *axioms* $A→A$ only with $A := \Phi$ ?

Comment: So doing an $LK-\Phi$ proof means we can have the logical axioms as our leaves and the nonlogical axioms, i.e., the elements $A\in \Phi$

Comment: If so, you have to start with the sequent $\rightarrow P(a, fa)$ (with $\Gamma = \Delta = \emptyset$) and then apply $\exists$-right to obtain the sequent : $\rightarrow \exists y P(a, y)$. But what about $a$ and $b$ ? are them *variables* or *terms* whatever ?

Comment: I believe a and b are variables, free ones, but the question doesn't specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $LK_Φ$ is the system obtained from $LK$ by adding $→A$ as initial sequents, for all $A \in Φ$.

Let $Φ = \{ Pafa \}$.

We have to start with the sequent :

> $→P(a,fa)$ (with $\Gamma = \Delta = \emptyset$)

and then apply ∃-right (with $fa$ as the *term* $t$ of the rule) to obtain the sequent :

> $→∃yP(a,y)$.

Then we apply the **Substitution lemma** [see Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521068428) (2001), page 68] :

> if $\Gamma \rightarrow C$ is derivable and $t$ is free for $x$ in $\Gamma, C$, then $\Gamma[t/x] \rightarrow C[t/x]$ is derivable.

We apply it to the end-sequent above, with $\Gamma = \emptyset$, $b$ as $t$ and $∃yP(a,y)$ as $C$; thus $C[t/x]$ is $∃yP(a,y)[b/a]=∃yP(b,y)$ to conclude :

> > $→∃yP(b,y)$.